# pandas dataframe use np.where and drop together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and I'd like to be able to use np.where to find certain elements based on a given condition, and then use pd.drop to erase the elements corresponding to the index found with np.where.

I.e.,

```
idx_to_drop = np.where(myDf['column10'].isnull() | myDf['column14'].isnull())
myDf.drop(idx_to_drop)
```

But I get a value error since drop does not take numpy array indexes.  Is there a way to achieve this using np.where and some drop function in pandas?

Comment: Can't you just do : `mask = myDf['column10'].isnull() | myDf['column14'].isnull()` and then `myDf[~mask]`?

Comment: @Divakar thanks a lot!  I could, I was looking also for some way to use np.where since it's very flexible in terms of operations I could do.  I personally also like knowing which indexes I am erasing.  Nonetheless this is more of a wish than needed since mask looks great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two common patterns to achieve that:

---

select those rows that DON'T satisfy your "dropping" condition or negate your conditions and select those rows that satisfy those conditions - [@jezrael has provided a good example for that approach](https://cloud.skytap.com/vms/35b17dc86d4dacb3c78ca423bbc79b8b/desktop).

---

drop the rows satisfying your "dropping" conditions:

```
df = df.drop(np.where(df['column10'].isnull() | df['column14'].isnull())[0])
```

**Timing**: first approach seems to be bit faster:

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,5), columns=list('abcde'))
df.loc[::7, ::2] = np.nan
df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [117]: df.shape
Out[117]: (1000000, 5)

In [118]: %timeit df[~(df['a'].isnull() | df['e'].isnull())]
10 loops, best of 3: 46.6 ms per loop

In [119]: %timeit df[df['a'].notnull() & df['e'].notnull()]
10 loops, best of 3: 39.9 ms per loop

In [120]: %timeit df.drop(np.where(df['a'].isnull() | df['e'].isnull())[0])
10 loops, best of 3: 65.5 ms per loop

In [122]: %timeit df.drop(np.where(df[['a','e']].isnull().any(1))[0])
10 loops, best of 3: 97.1 ms per loop

In [123]: %timeit df[df[['a','e']].notnull().all(1)]
10 loops, best of 3: 72 ms per loop
```

Comment: Maxu Are you sure? `There are two common patterns to achieve that:` ? I think drop method here is slowier and not recommended. Can you add some timings? I am offline now, onlyon phone, so I cannot do it.

Comment: Exactly. Boolean indexing is fastest.

Answer (score 3):

I  think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverse condition by `~`, [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and `|` (bitwise `or`):

```
print (~(myDf['column10'].isnull() | myDf['column14'].isnull()))
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

myDf[~(myDf['column10'].isnull() | myDf['column14'].isnull())]
```

Sample:

```
myDf = pd.DataFrame({'column10':[np.nan, 1,5], 'column14':[np.nan, 1,np.nan]})
print (myDf)
   column10  column14
0       NaN       NaN
1       1.0       1.0
2       5.0       NaN

myDf = myDf[~(myDf['column10'].isnull() | myDf['column14'].isnull())]
print (myDf)
   column10  column14
1       1.0       1.0
```

Solution with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and `&` (bitwise `and`)

```
myDf = myDf[myDf['column10'].notnull() & myDf['column14'].notnull()]
print (myDf)
   column10  column14
1       1.0       1.0
```

Another solutions with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
myDf = myDf[~myDf[['column10', 'column14']].isnull().any(axis=1)]
print (myDf)
   column10  column14
1       1.0       1.0
```

---

```
myDf = myDf[myDf[['column10', 'column14']].notnull().all(axis=1)]
print (myDf)
   column10  column14
1       1.0       1.0
```